# Two for loops inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question, I want two for loops to run on change function but there is an issue somewhere as with one for loop the code runs fine, but when i try to add a second one it doesn't, there is probably a syntax error in the code below. Any tip would be helpful.

```
$('#Q18v1_1').change(function() {   
     for (var ii = 1; i < 5; ii++)
     for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++)
     if ($('#Q18v1_' + ii).is(':checked')) {

        $("#Q18v2_" + ii + "_" + i).prop("disabled", false );

    } else{

        $("#Q18v2_" + ii + "_" + i).prop("disabled", true );


    }

});
```

Comment: In first `for` change `i < 5` to `ii < 5`.

Comment: probably a simpler way to do this, show sample html

Comment: @charlietfl yeah... that html is they key

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to nest the for loops. Then the structure should look like this:

```
for (var ii = 1; ii < 5; ii++) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
         ....
    }
}
```

Comment: `i` in outer loop?

Comment: Normally on stackoverflow you don't downvote answers, but just give better answers instead. Thats why you receive negative points when you donwnvote answers. It you really think my answer is so bad than please telly me why.

Comment: @charlietfl is correct, the i in the outer loop was also wrong.

Comment: @Meier i'm agree with you. dont so fast to downvote the answer. At least some1 try to help. Just comment first. if they ignore us or cant give the right answer, we can downvote the answer.